# React to object property change in an Array in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 app. In this app, I need to show a list of items and allow a user to choose items in the array. Currently, my component looks like this:

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in getItems()" :key="`item-${itemIndex}`">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" :id="`checkbox-${itemIndex}`" v-model="item.selected" />
        <label class="form-check-label" :for="`checkbox-${itemIndex}`">{{ item.name }} (selected: {{ item.selected }})</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" @click="generateItems">Generate Items</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { reactive } from 'vue';

  export default {
    data() {
      return itemCount: 0
    },

    methods: {
      generateItems() {
        this.itemCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
      },

      getItems() {
        let items = reactive([]);
        for (let i=0; i<this.itemCount; i++) {
          items.push({
            id: (i+1),
            selected: false,
            name: `Item #${i+1}`
          });
        }
        return items; 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I click select/deselect the checkbox, the "selected" text does not get updated. This tells me that I have not bound to the property properly. However, I'm also unsure what I'm doing wrong.

How do I bind a checkbox to the property of an object in an Array in Vue 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint in `getItems()`, or output a `console.log` in there, you will notice every time that you change a checkbox selection, it is getting called. This is because the `v-for` loop is re-rendered, and it'll call `getItems()` which will return it a fresh list of items with `selected` reset to `false` on everything. The one that was there before is no longer in use by anything.

To fix this, you could only call `getItems()` from `generateItems()` for example, and store that array some where - like in `data`, and change the `v-for` to iterate that rather than calling the `getItems()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Steve is right.

Here is a fixed version: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`item-${index}`">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" :id="`checkbox-${index}`" v-model="item.selected" />
        <label class="form-check-label" :for="`checkbox-${index}`">{{ item.name }} (selected: {{ item.selected }})</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" @click="generateItems">Generate Items</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { reactive } from 'vue';

  export default {
    data() {
      return { items: [] }
    },
    methods: {
      generateItems() {
        this.itemCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
        this.getRndItems();
      },
      getRndItems() {
        this.items = reactive([]);
        for (let i=0; i<this.itemCount; i++) {
          this.items.push({
            id: (i+1),
            selected: false,
            name: `Item #${i+1}`
          });
        }
      }      
    }
  }
</script>
```